# Как в GridView tr th добавить класс?

Tags: yii2, gridview

В *Yii* у виджета `GridView` можно настроить классы для отображения, например

`tableOptions` для тега `table`, `rowOptions` - для строк и т.д. Но я не могу никак найти  настройку, чтобы добавить класс в `table > thead > tr > th`.

Как можно добавить класс в этот тег?

Если есть возможность вообще свой шаблон написать для таблицы - было интересно узнать как. Может быть так проблему решил бы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал кастомный  класс для колонок

```
class DataColumn extends \yii\grid\DataColumn {

    public function renderHeaderCell() {
        $provider = $this->grid->dataProvider;
        if ($this->attribute !== null && $this->enableSorting &&
            ($sort = $provider->getSort()) !== false && $sort->hasAttribute($this->attribute)) {
            if (($direction = $sort->getAttributeOrder($this->attribute)) !== null) {
                Html::addCssClass($this->headerOptions, 'sorting_' . ($direction === SORT_DESC ? 'desc' : 'asc'));
            } else {
                Html::addCssClass($this->headerOptions, 'sorting');
            }
        }
        return Html::tag('th', $this->renderHeaderCellContent(), $this->headerOptions);
    }
}
```

который использую у грида

```
public $dataColumnClass = 'app\widgets\grid\DataColumn';
```